# audio player service stops when phone sleeps

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications, android-mediaplayer

I am running audio player service but If I put my phone on sleep the player stops or the background service I don't know what's the problem.

this is my music service class :

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "NEXT";
    public static final String ACTION_PREV = "PREVIOUS";
    public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "PLAY";
    public static final String ACTION_FORWARD = "FORWARD";
    public static final String ACTION_REWIND = "REWIND";
    public static final String ACTION_CONTINUE = "CONTINUE";
    ActionPlaying actionPlaying;
    Action action;

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public  IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }



    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    String actionName = intent.getStringExtra("myActionName");

        if (actionName != null) {
            switch (actionName)
            {
                case ACTION_PLAY:
                    if(actionPlaying!= null){
                        if(action!= null){
                        actionPlaying.playClicked();
                        action.playPauseClicked();
                    }}
                    break;
                case ACTION_NEXT:
                    if(actionPlaying != null){
                        actionPlaying.nextClicked();
                    }

                    break;
                case ACTION_PREV:
                    if(actionPlaying != null){
                        actionPlaying.prevClicked();

                    }

                    break;
                case ACTION_FORWARD:
                    if(actionPlaying != null){
                        actionPlaying.forwardClicked();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_REWIND:
                    if(actionPlaying != null){
                        actionPlaying.rewindClicked();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_CONTINUE:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        action.continueMediaPlayer();

            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    public void setCallBack(ActionPlaying actionPlaying){
        this.actionPlaying =  actionPlaying;
    }


    public void setCallBack(Action action) {
        this.action =  action;
    }

    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
           notificationManager.cancelAll();
         saveData();
        simpleExoPlayer.release();

    }

}
```

and this is my media player initialization :

```
public void prepareMedia() {
        isPlaying=true;
        simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(MediaPlayer_Activity.this).build();
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(audioUrl);
        simpleExoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaItem);
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare();
        simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(songPrevPosition);
    }
```

Please tell me what's wrong LogCat is not showing anything I don't know how to stop this and where the problem is....
please help

Answer (score 0):

After 9 Android version we have protections for simple service. Simple service can live 10 seconds, no more. You need to declare you service as `Foreground Service`. It will look like notification in status bar.

For fully information read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

Answer (score 0):

according to [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) :

- You need to upgrade your background process to foreground inorder to make it live without needing your application to be visible to the user.
- in order to change your service to foreground one, your service need to have a notification to inform the user that your music player service is working.

a simple foreground service code might look like this :

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Notification notification = buildStartingNotification();
        startForeground(startId, notification);
        ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }
private Notification buildStartingNotification() {

    int priority  =NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        priority = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        createNotificationChannel(priority);
    }
    Notification notification =
              new Notification.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Your_notification_title")
        .setContentText("Your_notification_description ")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setPriority(priority)
        .build();
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createNotificationChannel(int priority) {
        CharSequence name = getText("Your_Channel_Name");
        String description = getString("Your_Channel_Desc");
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, priority);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

**N.B** : if you're using application with (target_api > 26) you need to have also a notification channel which I included its code in `createNotificationChannel`, where your `CHANNEL_ID` could be any unique string id you want.
if you're wandering what's the meaning of notification channel ?
a notification channel is a mechanism built for android 8 or later to make the user turn off/on group of notification with same channel at once from setting.
as an example your application might have multiple notification channels (news/games/entertainment...etc), then the user can turn off news &games and leave only entertainment on.

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure you use foreground service. I suggest to you to start permanent notification like this:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            NotificationChannel channel;
 Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
            notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification notification = showStableMessage(this,
                    getString(R.string.app_desc),
                    "Message to user",
                    R.mipmap.ic_icon,
                    notifyPendingIntent);

            startForeground(NotificationUtil.STABLE_CHANNEL_NOTIFY_ID, notification);
        return  Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private Notification showStableMessage(Context context, String title, String message, int icon, PendingIntent intent) {
        NotificationChannel channel;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(STABLE_CHANNEL_ID,
                    STABLE_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Notification notification =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, STABLE_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(Html.fromHtml(message)).setPriority(PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE).build();
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        return notification;
    }
```

Second you have to put this in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application
.....>
    <service
                android:name=".data.service.MyService"
                android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
                android:enabled="true"/>
</application>
```